# What does this command mean?

Tags: command-line, apt, execute-command, pipe

While searching installation of lxqt I found `apt install` command for `lxqt-sudo | gksu`, `xfwm4 | x-window-manager`, `firefox | www-browser`. What does this commands mean? What is the difference with respect to only (`apt install`) `lxqt-sudo`, `gksu`, `xfwm4`, `firefox`.

It seems very basic, but unable to grasp. Can someone explain?

Comment: I suspect they mean use `lxqt-sudo` OR `gksu`  as they do pretty much the same thing, just call different toolkits to accomplish the goal.  Likewise `xfwm4` (xfce's window manager) OR x-window-manager (debian use xfwm4 where as Lubuntu use openbox).   You should provide a link to where you are asking about, as I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to install the LXQt desktop on your system? What is your system currently?

Comment: https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1627#issuecomment-441073915

Comment: my goal minimal lxqt install, without terminal, pcmanfm etc. but basic desktop functionalities should work flawlessly. shutdown currently not working under leave menu even after following [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxqt-session/+bug/1781392/comments/7). What i have done: `sudo apt install -f -y --no-install-recommends kwin lxqt-config lxqt-panel lxqt-policykit lxqt-qtplugin lxqt-session lxqt-sudo sddm dolphin konsole` over 'minimal ubuntu' install

Comment: Well, I find the two lead developers there to be pretty frank and blunt :) Could you please clarify your question? What are the exact commands you issued and what were the complete responses in the terminal. Please use copy/paste [between code tags]([markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)) to provide the information.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question; it's far easier to read allowing better formatting.  You haven't said what release of Ubuntu, you've also mentioned `pcmanfm` (which is for LXDE not LXQt; `pcmanfm-qt` is the supported LXQt program)  LXQt uses `pcmanfm-qt` for some functionality of the desktop too  (eg. display of icons ..)

Comment: @guiverc, Ok, it's ubuntu 18.04LTS, `pcmanfm-qt` and `lxqt`. It should be platform independent question. I just want to know, what is the difference between running `sudo apt install lxqt-sudo | gksu` and only `sudo apt install lxqt-sudo`, and so on...

Comment: LXQt was not supported in Ubuntu until 18.10;  Lubuntu NEXT (which used LXQt on earlier releases of Ubuntu) is now EOL, as the earlier Lubuntu's used LXDE in LTS releases (with exception of the now EOL Lubuntu Next). The packages may have problems which are fixed in 18.10 & up (but unfixed earlier as they are abandoned due EOL).  My first comment answered that question already (your link showed it accurate though a guess; | used as an *OR*)

Comment: Another side-effect related to *documented* flaws is that they may be hard to find, given the lubuntu's loss of their server (https://lubuntu.me/infrastructure-data-loss/) which will effect the Lubuntu Next particularly (ie. LXQt in 18.04 & before) as due to EOL status, there was no desire to bother restoring the documented issues that no longer matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipeline character, `|` indicates `OR`, i.e., either of the two `lxqt-sudo` and `gksu` can be used. Similarly, `xfwm4` or `x-window-manager` and `firefox` or `www-browser`.